passing query params on generateStaticParams not working | Nextjs 14.2.17
On the parent page, there is a list of projects on client side (using use client with useEffect) and when the user clicks on a specific project -->
 <Link
                                        key={index}
                                        prefetch={true}
                                        href={{
                                            pathname: `/project/client-projects/${clientProject.project_id}`,
                                            query: {
                                                squad_id: clientProject.vendor_squad_id,
                                                user_id: clientProject.user_id
                                            }
                                        }}

I want to pass this squad_id and user_id to next page where it will be used on generateStaticParams function
here I am using like this
export async function generateStaticParams({
params: { squad_id, user_id },
}: {
params: { squad_id: string, user_id: string }
}) {

console.log(`id on params ${squad_id}`);

const response = await getClientProjectApi({
    "vendor_squad_id": squad_id,
    "user_id": user_id,
    "sort_by": "newest_first",
});

return response.allProjects?.data?.map((project: any) => ({
    projectid: project["project_id"],
    workid: project["work_id"]
}))}

folder structure

finally, I get this error


If you are using Next.js v15, request apis are now async.
Please check out breaking changes in v15
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-15#async-request-apis-breaking-change

I am on Nextjs 14.2.17 version also mentioned in the above questioned
